# Sockets & Inter communication Among Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

I am using Multithreaded TCP Server. 
Each socket is created as a separate thread for each client. I would like send data to all clients via send() method of socket. Problem I am facing here is, it sends data to current thread (from which it received) only.

I could not find good documentation for inter thread communication for Python.

Any solution to my problem so that I can send data to all clients.

Thanks.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    """
    A server with multithreading to handle multiple clients.
    """

    import select
    import socket
    import sys
    import threading
    import logging
    import datetime

    class Server:
        def __init__(self):
            self.host = ''
            self.port = 25000
            self.backlog = 5
            self.size = 1024
            self.server = None

        def open_socket(self):
            try:
                self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                self.server.bind((self.host,self.port))
                self.server.listen(5)
                lc.append(self.server)
            except socket.error, (value,message):
                if self.server:
                    self.server.close()
                print "Could not open socket: " + message
                sys.exit(1)

        def run(self):
            self.open_socket()
            input = [self.server,sys.stdin]
            running = 1
            while running:
                inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[])

                for s in inputready:
                    if s == self.server:
                        c = Client(self.server.accept())
                        c.start()
                        threads.append(c)

            # close all threads
            self.server.close()
            for c in threads:
                c.join()

    class Client(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self,(client,address)):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.client = client
            self.address = address
            self.size = 1024
            dc[address[0]]=client#address[1]
            logging.info('%s added successfully...',address[0])


        def run(self):
            running = 1
            print dc
            while running:
                data = str(self.client.recv(self.size))
                #print dc

                if data.strip() == '0x01':
                    sendtoAll()
                elif data.strip() == '0x02':
                    self.client.send("version"+data)
                elif data.strip() == '0x03':#return current time
                    print datetime.datetime.now()
                    self.client.send(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                else:
                    self.client.send("empty")
                    #self.client.close()
                    #running = 0
def sendtoAll():
        for i, sock in dc.items():
            print "Address:Sockets = ", i,sock
            try:
                print "sending to %s by Thread "%i
                sock.send("data"+str(threading.current_thread().getName()))
            except socket.error,e:
                print "error socket %s\n" % e
                sock.close()
                del lc[i]

if __name__ == "__main__":
        dc={}       #dict to store ip-address:scokets pair
        lc=[]       #tuples to store all sockets
        threads=[]  #holds threads
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
        logging.info('Starting Server Object...')
        s = Server()
        s.run()
```

**And Client Code is**

```
import socket
import sys

host = '192.168.1.4'
port = 25000
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
sys.stdout.write('%')

while 1:
    # read from keyboard
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line == '\n':
        break
    s.send(line)
    data = s.recv(size)
    sys.stdout.write(data)
    sys.stdout.write('\n%')
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TCP socket is one of two endpoints. There is no such thing as "broadcast" in TCP. If you want to send a single message to all your clients, you will have to send it to every one of them individually.

If you use a suitable container for all your client objects, it shoudl "just" be a matter of iterating across this, sending your message to each one.

Comment: I did not say I want to broadcast. If you see code carefully you will find that I am sending via loop to each socket (just fn name is broadcast). But message is sent to one socket at a time . problem persists.

Message is actually queued for non-current thread and delivered when that thread is called again.

Comment: @Pujan Srivasta: If you use TCP sockets, you have to send it down one socket at a time. You cannot send on multiple sockets "at once" and you cannot connect to more than one client per socket. The only way to send to multiple clients in one go is broadcast (actually, broadcast or multicast), but that only works with UDP. Also, make sure you're not clobbering the socket for the previous client when you save the socket for the new client.

Comment: Thanks Vatine, I did not know that I can not use multiple socket at once. Actually I will use above code among different networks (globally routable) where Multicast will not be available ofcourse. Do you think UDP is good choice ? or any solution thanks.

Comment: You can use multiple sockets, but you cannot store two sockets in the same variable. Typically, you will be wanting to open a socket to accept incoming requests ONCE, do a listen (this make sit ready to receive connections), then use select or accept (the former for seeing if there is an incoming connection; the latter blocks until there is a connection). Each accept call returns a new socket, save these away in a list or something.

Comment: This answer seems to have little to do with the question asked.  The comments also make very little sense; the OP's code keeps a dictionary with all of the client connections, and iterates over it to send a message to each.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your threads objects (if any) [iterable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable) and you make a "broadcast" function that just iterate through your threads and use their sockets to send the information.

Or if you don't have an object per threads you can always just have a list of sockets and do pretty much the same thing.

Make sure that you use locks correctly based on your needs (Either for all the socket or each individual sockets)